# Cartthrob Gateway Fields Custom Html Seems to Be Missing

Tags: cartthrob

I'm using Cartthrob's {exp:cartthrob:checkout_form} tag pair. Currently it is using the {gateway_fields} variable to output the right fields. I would like to customize the form using my own html and my understanding is that I should be able to find the html in the Cartthrob payments page. For some reason though, that html is not showing up when I select the dpm payment method (which is what we are using). I can see html to copy when I select other payment methods though. Any ideas why it is not there for dpm?

Comment: Do you mean no HTML shows up in the control panel when you select DPM? What happens if you select it as a payment gateway and then copy the HTML from your checkout template?

Comment: @Tyssen Yep. That's exactly what I mean. When I copy the html from the checkout page and put it inside my {exp:cartthrob:checkout_form} tag pair, it shows the form but the action is wrong (well, it is pointing to my site not authorize.net anyway). Then, when I submit the form, the default form appears (at the same /cart/checkout url) with the expected (authorize.net) action but with a number of default fields that I don't want. So, it appears that cartthrob uses my form fields when I send a get request to /cart/checkout but returns the default one after sending post requests.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to change the default form?

Comment: Can you post some template code?